# How do I test whether a text node intervenes between the current node and a defined preceding sibling?

Tags: xslt, xpath

In XPath/XSLT 2.0, how do I test whether a text node intervenes between the current node and a preceding sibling `<lb/>`, regardless whether non-text nodes intervene?

XML:

```
<lb/>I'd like to test whether this text exists.<someNode/><currentNode/>
```

Bonus question: what is the desired syntax if the `<lb/>` may be either a sibling of the current node or of the parent node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::text() >> preceding-sibling::lb">` tests whether there is a preceding sibling text node after a preceding sibling `lb` element: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCK.

In general (if there can be more than one element or text node) I think you need to use `some $sib in preceding-sibling::lb satisfies some $text in preceding-sibling::text() satisfies $sib >> $text`.